# Laravel Проверка коллекции на пустоту

Tags: laravel

Есть такая конструкция

```
@if (!$lessons->isEmpty())
   Занятия есть
@else
 занятий нет
@endif
```

Почему такая конструкция не работает или как проверить модель на пустоту?
dd показывает что коллекция пуста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что проверял внутри foreach, вынес за foreach и все заработало

```
@if (!$lessons->isEmpty())
    @foreach ($lessons as $lesson)

    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сначала проверить на существование объекта, а потом уже на количество элементов

```
@if ($lessons && $lessons->count())
   Занятия есть
@else
 занятий нет
@endif
```

Comment: К сожалению такой вариант тоже не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
@forelse ($lessons as $lesson)
    <article>{{ $lesson->title }}</article>
@empty
    <p>Занятий нет.</p>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
введите сюда код

@if($categories->count() !== 0)
  <p>content</p>
@else
<p>not content</p>
@endif
```

Попробуйте так, у меня работает.